# can you stretch background height when slideDown()/slideUp() happens

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I made a hidden accordion like hidden menu here a submenu appears below when the parent `li` is clicked using the `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`. But when the submenu slides down, the entire menu moves over the set height of the containing `div` 's background. However I cant put `.animate()` in my JQuery code for the `.slideDown()`/`.slideUp()` portions since not all of the submenu's are the same combined height.

Demo: http://codepen.io/PorototypeX/pen/Dvjwx

Figured I'd put the JQuery here too (if you want to see the other code here too just ask and I'll edit it):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#topnav a").click(function () {
            var el = $(this).parent();
            if (el.hasClass('active') && $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                var active = el.siblings('.active');
                $(this).next().slideUp();
            }
            else if (el.hasClass('active') && !$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                var active = el.siblings('.active');
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            }
            else if (!el.hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
                var active = el.siblings('.active');
                active.children('ul:first').slideUp();
                active.removeClass('active');
                el.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix that easily with some CSS. [**Forked Pen**](http://codepen.io/UltCombo/pen/Blbwe)

Explanation: removed the hardcoded height from `div.backing` and `.navbar`'s `top`, added some `padding` to `.backing` in order to show a bit of background above and below the `.navbar`. Now the element's background will grow/shrink along with its contents. Set the padding value to your liking.